# Why do drawing commands like 'rectangle' and 'line' ignore 'hold off'?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to display a changing rectangle in a loop, with pause, and it ignores hold off (which actually suppose to be default).

Here's a simplified version's code :

```
clc; close all; clear all;

rect = [10 10 20 30];

figure
axis([0 200 0 50]);

for i = 1 : 15
    rect(1) = rect(1) + i;
    rectangle('Position', rect, 'edgeColor', [1 0 0]);
    hold off;
    pause(0.2);
end
```

Is it on purpose?
Am I missing something?
What can I do to make the previous rectangles disappear, aside from ploting it in white after each iteration?

Thanks..

**edit :**

The very simplified version was solved, but if I want to also plot another thing on the same figure, the other plot ignores hold off.
What should I do in this case?

Thanks again.

```
clc; close all; clear all;

rect = [10 10 20 30];

figure
axis([0 200 0 50]);

h1 = [];
for i = 1 : 15
    rect(1) = rect(1) + i;
    delete(h1);
    h1 = rectangle('Position', rect, 'edgeColor', [1 0 0]);
    hold on
    plot (5 + 5 * i, 5, '*g');
    hold off
    pause(0.2);
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update: Matlab R2014b and later

With the  [**update of the handle graphics engine**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html) in Matlab R2014b the notation in the documentation changed a little. There are no distinctive sites for
**Core Graphics Objects** and **Plot Objects** anymore, but [**here**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-object-properties.html) you can see that the two kind of objects are now called **Plotting Function Objects** and **Primitive Objects**.

---

The reason is, that there is a difference between [**Core Graphics Objects**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/core-graphics-objects.html) made for drawing and its subgroup [**Plot Objects**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plot-objects.html) with the purpose of displaying data, using Core Graphics Objects to do that.

**Core Graphics Objects**

> Core graphics objects include basic drawing primitives:
>
> - Line, text, and polygon shells (patch objects)
> - Specialized objects like surfaces, which are composed of a    rectangular grid of vertices
> - Images
> - Light objects, which are not visible but affect the way some objects    are colored

**Plot Objects**

> A number of high-level plotting functions create plot objects. The
> properties of plot objects provide easy access to the important
> properties of the core graphics objects that the plot objects contain.

A characteristic example would be the commands `line` and `plot` - which are basically the same. But they belong to different groups. If one wants to plot data, he uses `plot`, task done. If one wants to "draw" something with **lines** its easier you wouldn't always need to `hold` everything.

So to answer your question: **Yes, it is on purpose.**

And to solve your problem, I would write a new rectangle function using `plot`:

```
function h = plotRectangle(posX, posY, width, height)

x = [posX posX+width posX+width  posX        posX];
y = [posY posY       posY+height posY+height posY];

h = plot(x,y);

end
```

Respectively:

```
function h = plotRectangle(PosVector)

X = PosVector;

x = [X(1) X(1)+X(3) X(1)+X(3)  X(1)        X(1)];
y = [X(2) X(2)      X(2)+X(4)  X(2)+X(4)   X(2)];

h = plot(x,y);

end
```

The latter you can now use with your code:

```
rect = [10 10 20 30];

figure
axis([0 200 0 50]);

for i = 1 : 15
    rect(1) = rect(1) + i;
    plotRectangle(rect);
    hold off;
    pause(0.2);
end
```

Comment: Superb answer. I'd avoid over loading the [`handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html) function with an actual handle.

Answer (score 2):

Modified your code:

```
clc; close all; clear all;

rect = [10 10 20 30];

figure
axis([0 200 0 50]);

h1 = [];
for i = 1 : 15
    rect(1) = rect(1) + i;
    delete(h1);
    h1 = rectangle('Position', rect, 'edgeColor', [1 0 0]);
    pause(0.2);
end
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I was just typing up this same solution :). Note that "hold off" doesn't work because rectangle is a special plot function. This solution involves saving the handle to the rectangle so that you can delete it later.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new, but it doesn't help in the general case - I'll edit my question to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method that lakesh already proposed. Below I added an additional handle for the second plot.

```
clc; close all; clear all;

rect = [10 10 20 30];

figure; hold on;
axis([0 200 0 50]);

h1 = [];
h2 = [];
for i = 1 : 15
    rect(1) = rect(1) + i;
    delete(h1);
    delete(h2);
    h1 = rectangle('Position', rect, 'edgeColor', [1 0 0]);
    h2 = plot (5 + 5 * i, 5, '*g');

    pause(0.2);
end
```