# Drawing a 2-D figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Please If anyone can give a hint on drawing this in matlab
  ( I am not asking for the actual code but just a hint....)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard do give a hint, as it is just one line of code.

```
rectangle('Position',[1,2,5,6])
```

---

To actually see the rectangle you need to set the axes limits:

```
axis equal
xlim([0,8])
ylim([0,9])
```

[image]

Regarding your comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208301/why-do-drawing-commands-like-rectangle-and-line-ignore-hold-off/25209704#25209704) which gives a little introduction into the [**core graphics objects**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/core-graphics-objects.html) you're lookling for.

**Core Graphics Objects**

> Core graphics objects include basic drawing primitives:
>
> - Line, text, and polygon shells (patch objects)
> - Specialized objects like surfaces, which are composed of a    rectangular grid of vertices
> - Images

Comment: Thanks for the answer .I didn't search google as I wanted to construct it myself because in future I may encounter a figure that doesn't have a built in method....is there some way we can contruct it ourselves..

Comment: Alright, have a look at my edit.

Comment: thanks for the nice referal.....

Answer (score 1):

To draw an arbitrary figure you can use [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). For example, this draws a trapezoid:

```
x = [1 7 4 2 1]; %// x coordinates of vertices
y = [1 1 3 3 1]; %// y coordinates of vertices
plot(x,y);       %// do the plotting
axis([0 8 0 4])  %// set axis limits
```

As you se, you specify the vertices and `plot` (in its default behaviour) joins them with straight lines. You need to specify the first vertex again as a last vertex to close the polygon.

[image]

Comment: For "drawing" multiple objects it is may easier to use `line` instead if `plot` as it does not require to `hold` the previous object.

Comment: @LuisMendo can you please help me with this:there are four vertices in trapezoid ,then why did you enter 5 points in the x-values and y-values respectively....

Comment: @coool because for a closed polygon you need start and end point to be equal.