# How to plot on the same figure with different data and delete the old plot(s)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

For faster operation I want to update a plot with different data in MATLAB. If I use `plot3` it will open a new figure every time, which is time consuming. I cannot use `hold` command as I do not want earlier plots. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the plot object initially and then update its `'XData'`,`'YData'` and `'ZData'` properties according to the new values:

```
axis([0 1 0 1]);
h = plot3(NaN,NaN,NaN,'.'); %// intiallize plot object
for n = 1:20
    x = rand(1,100);
    y = rand(1,100);
    z = rand(1,100); %// example new data for the plot
    set(h, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z); %// update properties of plot object
    pause(.1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the short version of one of my [**previous answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29373562/2605073) to a different question.

If you want to create a new plot to the previous figure window by using **Plot Objects**/functions like e.g. `plot3`, the `hold` command is necessary in any case (apart from you're using [**Core Graphics Objects**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209704/2605073)).

For deleting the previous plots you have two options:

1. [**`clf`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) (clear figure) which will reset the figure and axes objects (delete all axes objects inside the figure) and therefore is probably not much of a performance plus.
2. [**`cla`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html) (clear axes) which will just clear the axes (delete all graphics objects inside the axes object) but keep all labels and axes limits.

I think the last option is what you're looking for.

**Test code:**

```
figure
plot( [10 20], [10 20] );
xlim( [0,100] ); ylim( [0,100] ); hold on
xlabel( 'x' );
ylabel( 'y' );

pause(1)
cla
plot( [20 30], [20 30] );
```